# conveniently using two personas in github

Tags: git, github

i like to maintain public and corporate repositories. both on github.

is there a convenient way to have two authors on the same box without fiddling with your options or changing .git/log files before pushing?

I'm perfectly fine with a solution that works with one author for each repository, as long as it is not too much work everytime i clone a new one.

any ideas? what do you like to do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `user.name` and `user.email` settings on a per-repo basis.

```
# In your repo
git config user.name "John Doe"
git config user.email "john@doe.com"
```

Comment: I have just proposed an edition of your answer with the corresponding git commands.

Comment: i was thinking about something in ~/.gitconfig that would use the correct username/email depending on the target host. one name for github.com, another for mycorp.github.com, and another for bitbucket.com. right now i'm entering each repo and typing `git config user.name gcb_[github|corporate|bitbucket]`.